# ANR Android keyDispatchingTimedOut (AIR 4.0)

Tags: android, multithreading, air, starling-framework, android-anr-dialog

I have developed a game on AIR using Starling Framework. I am receiving a lot of ANR's from users. The game involves drag - drop mechanism and it is turn based game so there is a timer running on background.

Many ANR's involve similar stack traces to the dump below.

```
DALVIK THREADS:(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)    
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE    
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41f44508 self=0x4003e008    
| sysTid=5019 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1075220272    
| schedstat=( 312982116691 68901855364 485609 ) utm=28822 stm=2476 core=1    
#00 pc 0000dc80 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)    
#01 pc 00012db4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)    
#02 pc 00012e10 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)    
#03 pc 00012ea8 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_join+108)    
#04 pc 001dc775 /data/data/air.com.macarongames.riskokey/lib/libCore.so

at com.adobe.air.customHandler.callTimeoutFunction(Native Method)
at com.adobe.air.customHandler.handleMessage(customHandler.java:22)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
"Thread-2107" prio=5 tid=22 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42a55750 self=0x6042a7d0
| sysTid=5946 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1615378384
| schedstat=( 689605688 91613777 1862 ) utm=56 stm=12 core=0
#00 pc 0000dc80 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 00012174 /system/lib/libc.so
#02 pc 0012ad95 /data/data/air.com.macarongames.riskokey/lib/libCore.so
#03 pc 0010e787 /data/data/air.com.macarongames.riskokey/lib/libCore.so
#04 pc 001aa151 /data/data/air.com.macarongames.riskokey/lib/libCore.so
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AudioTrack" prio=10 tid=21 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42a861c0 self=0x6042c910
| sysTid=5945 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1614836480
| schedstat=( 649810821 215698216 7041 ) utm=24 stm=40 core=1
#00 pc 0000d300 /system/lib/libc.so (nanosleep+12)
#01 pc 0001a89f /system/lib/libc.so (usleep+30)
#02 pc 0003a2ef /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::processAudioBuffer(android::sp<android::AudioTrack::AudioTrackThread> const&)+402)
#03 pc 0003a3ab /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::AudioTrackThread::threadLoop()+70)
#04 pc 0001103b /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+94)
#05 pc 0004b44b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#06 pc 00010bb5 /system/lib/libutils.so
#07 pc 00012d70 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#08 pc 000124c8 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42b02af0 self=0x60e4da28
| sysTid=5178 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1540363888
| schedstat=( 21789549 60577394 30 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42a4d218> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=17 (AsyncTask #3)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=23 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42a3cdc8 self=0x5bca8f30
| sysTid=5167 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1539370024
| schedstat=( 109405514 857849122 431 ) utm=8 stm=2 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42a752a8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=23 (AsyncTask #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Timer-1" prio=5 tid=20 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42af1508 self=0x5bca8708
| sysTid=5096 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1540493584
| schedstat=( 119934078 250213626 359 ) utm=9 stm=2 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42af1508> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:238)

"Timer-0" prio=5 tid=19 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42aff6e0 self=0x5bd20628
| sysTid=5095 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1540493520
| schedstat=( 147308362 235565175 342 ) utm=14 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42aff6e0> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:238)
```

From what I have analyzed many of these traces are in the similar form such as after "AudioTrack" thread, there comes an "AsyncTask #3" which is the first thread waiting.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you solve your issues?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I posted on Adobe bugbase but they responded that this bug is not AIR related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and loop a background sound on volume 0, that is what worked for me. In my case it prevented the audio channel from closing and thus the threads never locked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it out and post my result.